# Ошибка с парсингом JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

Привет!
Пытаюсь спарсить приходящий JSON, но получается как-то криво. Не могу понять в чем ошибка.

```
let stringURL = "http://www.coincap.io/history/7day/BTC"

func getDataForChartFrom(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let price = json["price"].arrayObject,
               let marketCap = json["market_cap"].arrayObject {

                for dataArray in price as! [[AnyObject]] {
                    print(dataArray)
                    for (date, price) in dataArray.enumerated() {
                        print("Цена - \(price)")
                        print("Дата - \(date)")
                        self.cryptoDateArray.append(date)
                        self.cryptoPriceArray.append(price as! Double)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Принты показывают мне следующее:

```
[1503444567000, 4057.71] Цена - 1503444567000 Дата - 0 Цена - 4057.71 Дата - 1 
[1503445464000, 4085.18] Цена - 1503445464000 Дата - 0 Цена - 4085.18 Дата - 1
```

А мне нужно что-то вроде

```
 [1503444567000, 4057.71] Цена - 4057.71 Дата - 1503444567000
 [1503445464000, 4085.18] Цена - 4085.18 Дата - 1503445464000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парсинг JSON в Swift 4 (используя protocol Decodable) можно сделать так.

```
import Foundation

struct CoinCapHistory : Decodable {
    let market_cap : [[Double]]
    let price: [[Double]]
    let volume: [[Double]]
}

func __test_so_712362() {
    print("[TEST]: \(#function)")

    let stringURL = "http://www.coincap.io/history/7day/BTC"
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let url = URL(string: stringURL)!

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if data != nil {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let history = try! decoder.decode(CoinCapHistory.self, from:data!)
            let index = history.price.count - 1
            let (date, price) = (Date(timeIntervalSince1970: history.price[index][0]/1000.0), history.price[index][1])
            print("\tДата: \(date), Цена: \(price)")
        } else {
            print(error!)
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    task.resume()
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout:DispatchTime.distantFuture)

    print("[/TEST]")
}
```

Результат будет как вами ожидалось: дата и цена.

```
[TEST]: __test_so_712362()
    Дата: 2017-08-31 19:49:32 +0000, Цена: 4703.42
[/TEST]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема в использовании метода `.enumerated()`. 
Из документации:

> enumerated() - 
>   Returns a sequence of pairs (n, x), where n represents a consecutive integer starting at zero, and x represents an element of the sequence.

То есть по документации все отрабатывает верно, в качестве цены вы получаете значение из массива, а в качестве даты - последовательный int. Таким образом, вы просто неправильно обходите массив.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать по-другому.